# Sort list of objects and Get object with latest time in Python

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, datetime

we have

```
[
   {
    "StartTs": "2023-02-12 15:49:38"
    },
    {
     "StartTs": "2023-02-08 19:02:00"
    },
    {
     "StartTs": "2023-02-22 17:02:00"
     }
 ]
```

Need to sort this by startTs Value and get latest object in Python

Expected Output:
{ "StartTs": "2023-02-22 17:02:00" }

Expected Output:
{ "StartTs": "2023-02-22 17:02:00" }

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach.

Initialize the list:

```
my_list = [
    {
        "StartTs": "2023-02-12 15:49:38"
    },
    {
        "StartTs": "2023-02-08 19:02:00"
    },
    {
         "StartTs": "2023-02-22 17:02:00"
    }
 ]
```

Use the [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-s-a-negative-index) built-in with a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-s-a-negative-index) function to order the list of dicts by the `StartTs` field to return the sorted list.

```
sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x["StartTs"])

# returns: 
# [{'StartTs': '2023-02-08 19:02:00'}, {'StartTs': '2023-02-12 15:49:38'}, {'StartTs': '2023-02-22 17:02:00'}]
```

Use a [negative index](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-s-a-negative-index) to retrieve the last item of that list.

```
sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x["StartTs"])[-1]

# returns: 
# {'StartTs': '2023-02-22 17:02:00'}
```

If you wish, you can also retrieve the value of the start time string from the dict using the key:

```
sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x["StartTs"])[-1]["StartTs"]

# returns: 
#'2023-02-22 17:02:00'
```

Answer (score -1):

If your object *only* contains those StartTs key/value pairs, try this reverse sort inside a list comprehension:

Where `list1` is your original object...

```py
list2 = [{'StartTs': y} for y in sorted([x['StartTs'] for x in list1], reverse = True)]

print(list2)

[{'StartTs': '2023-02-22 17:02:00'}, {'StartTs': '2023-02-12 15:49:38'}, {'StartTs': '2023-02-08 19:02:00'}]

print(list2[0]) # get latest

{'StartTs': '2023-02-22 17:02:00'}
```

It's actually a nested list comprehension. `y` is picked from the sorted values of `x` and put back into a list of dictionaries. `x` is picked from a reverse-sorted list of timestamp strings in the original `list1`.

If you only need the timestamp values themselves and don't care if they're inside a dictionary or not, try this instead:

```py
list2 = sorted([x['StartTs'] for x in list1], reverse = True)

print(list2)

['2023-02-22 17:02:00', '2023-02-12 15:49:38', '2023-02-08 19:02:00']

print(list2[0]) # gets latest

'2023-02-22 17:02:00'
```

Comment: Very useful as a new contributor if whoever marked my reply down would explain *why*.